# How to download a game from steam using wget

Tags: linux, windows-10

I was wondering if I could stop my current download (currently on Windows), start my Linux Distro (native installed) and mount the windows drive, then download there the game via wget or something similar. That would be great, because then I could do something on my linux while the game is downloading in the background and so I don't have to wait an eternity on windows where I can't do much (I do Kernel programming and such things)

Comment: Doesn't Steam have a linux version? It might be worth looking into if you can mount the drive and then use the linux version of steam to continue the download of the game to the windows drive, then you wouldn't have to worry about wget. You'd need to make sure it doesn't try to download a linux version of the game while you're using the linux Steam to download it.

Comment: I'm doubtful this would work, unfortunately. Steam has an opinionated way it likes to install games after downloading them that would be difficult to replicate on your own. And it's also possible (although this is a shot in the dark) that instead of downloading a game as a single file, Steam sends it as multiple blobs that the Steam client knows how to deal with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess Steam does not allow you to download games just via the command line.

There are loads of things I don't know how steam would deal with, like checking your licence to the game, is you were just to download a steam game via command line without having a steam install on your machine.

So I would say, before bashing your head on a problem like this, just go download Steam (theres a linux distribution) and download the game via it. There's no need in having a hard time for hours while you can just download the game you want it 2-3 clicks.

(Really at the end of the day I would guess that if you can download the game via command line it will just package steam into it if you don't have it anyways.)

Comment: There is, but you need to use `steamcmd` not `wget` -- although it'll only download the version of the game appropriate to the platform you're currently running on.